# how to parse specific portion of text file using two delimiters or strings in SCALA

Tags: scala, csv, scala-collections

I have sample.txt file 
The file contains logs with date and time.

For example,

```
10.10.2012:
erewwetrt=1
wrtertret=2
ertertert=3
;
10.10.2012:
asdafdfd=1
adadfadf=2
adfdafdf=3
;
10.12.2013:
adfsfsdfgg=1
sdfsdfdfg=2
sdfsdgsdg=3
;
12.12.2012:
asdasdas=1
adasfasdf=2
dfsdfsdf=3
;
```

I just want to retrive only year 2012 data, that is between12.12.2012: to ;
How can I do this in scla or spark scala.
finally I need to remove = with comma and save it in csv format.
How can I do it.

Comment: it would help clarify your need if you could show the end result you want

Answer (score 0):

To extract that specific part you can use this:

```
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    val text = "10.10.2012:\nerewwetrt=1\nwrtertret=2\nertertert=3\n;\n10.10.2012:\nasdafdfd=1\nadadfadf=2\nadfdafdf=3\n;\n10.12.2013:\nadfsfsdfgg=1\nsdfsdfdfg=2\nsdfsdgsdg=3\n;\n12.12.2012:\nasdasdas=1\nadasfasdf=2\ndfsdfsdf=3\n;"
    val lines = text.split("\n")
    val extracted = lines.dropWhile(_ != "12.12.2012:").drop(1).takeWhile(_ != ";")
    extracted.foreach(println(_))
  }
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, thank you...I use spark apache libraries,val file = sc.textFile("/home/user/logs/simple.txt")
    val dd = file.map(_.split("=").map(_.trim).mkString(","))
  dd.saveAsTextFile("/home/user/logs/simple_out2.txt").....   It shows dropWhile not part of rdd... how can I do it with sparkcontext...

Comment: If the dataset is small you can use `DataSet.collect` which will convert your dataset to `Iterable`, then you will have all standard collection ops available. After extracting the part you need you can convert the iterable to dataset again.